# Parse SQL Query string to get a map of values

Tags: java, sql, sql-parser

I have a java project where PreparedStatements are not being used in any of the SQL query. Now I want to implement PreparedStatements for all those queries. Instead of modifying each query by putting '?' , I want to write a function which takes SQL query string which parses it and returns the map of values of various SQL clauses.

```
public class SQLParser {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    String sqlString = "select * from table t where columnA = 'hello' and columnB = 'hai'";
    Map<Integer,String> values = new HashMap<>();
    values = parseQuery(sqlString);
    System.out.println(values);   // prints  { {1,'hello'} , {2,'hai'} }
    }

    private static Map<Integer,String> parseQuery(String sqlString) {
        Map<Integer,String> values = new HashMap<>();
        //
        //  ????  I want this function 
        //
        return values;
        
    }

}
```

Few examples are

sqlString : select * from table t where columnA = 'hello' AND columnB = 'hai'
output :  { {1,'hello'} , {2,'hai'} }

sqlString : select * from table t where columnA IN ('hello' ,'hai')
output :  { {1,'hello'} , {2,'hai'} }

sqlString : select * from table t where columnA > 17 AND columnB BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
output :  { {1,'17'} , {2, '10' } , {3, '20'} }

Basically It should support all possible clauses and their combinations.

Comment: If the keys of your map are incremental numbers, wouldn't a list be enough?

Comment: Anyway, you're basically asking how to write a parser for SQL (which SQL dialect, btw?), which seems no small feat if you ask me. I'm not sure it can fit a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: You're going to have to change the code for every query anyway, whether to use your magic statement parser/preparer or to use a `PreparedStatement` directly.   Could you actually develop that magic parser/preparer and then modify every query to use it, in less time than it would take to just rewrite every query as a `PreparedStatement`?  How many queries are we talking about here?

Comment: I think you miss something here. The point to use PreparedStatement is to avoid SQL injection. But if you first create your SQL as a string from your parameters, the injection can take place at this point and your parser will happily parse the malicious SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to implement it will be creating SQL parser. It is huge task. If you decide to go this way you can look at my [parser](https://github.com/a-e-tsvetkov/jdbc-to-elasticsearch/tree/master/driver-sql-parser)(Scala), it is not even close to being finished though.

Alternative approach is to create regexp to capture all literal. You only need scanner for that, which is easier.